# Representative system of congruence classes in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find a representative system of classes of the following equivalence relation in $\mathbb{Q}$ seen as $1 \times 1$ matrices:

For $A,B,P \in \mathbb{Q}:$

$A$ is congruent to $B$ $\iff \exists$ invertable $P: A=P^t B P$

For rational numbers, we get $A=P^t B P \iff A=P^2B$ with $P\neq0$.

It is clear $0$ has a class of its own.

If I set $A=1$, I get $\sqrt{B^{-1}}=P$, which would mean $1$ is congruent to all rationals which have a rational root.

If I set $A=2$, I get $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{B^{-1}}=P$. Does that cover all positive $B\in \mathbb{Q}$, such that their root is irrational?

I suspect that it must involve the roots of all primes, but I do not know how to prove it.

If not, how can I get a system of representatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from zero, I reckon a system of representatives is $\pm m$
where $m$ runs through all *squarefree* positive integers, that is
those not divisible by a square of prime (so $m=1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,13,14,15,17,19,\ldots$).

Comment: Right. For non-zero integers $a,b$ we have $a/b \equiv (a/b)b^2=ab,$ and $ab$ is equivalent to exactly one member of your set.